# Select2 version 4.0 ¿Por qué al presionar enter para activar un botón también se vuelve a abrir la caja de elemento del select?

Tags: jquery, web, aplicación-web, select2

esta es la primera vez que hago una pregunta aquí , mi problema es que tengo un pequeño formulario de 3 campos y 1 de esos 3 campos es un select que tiene la librería select2, e hice una función usando jquery que al presionar enter en cualquier lugar de la página web, accione de forma automática el evento click de un botón, lo que pasa es que no solo hace eso si no también al solo seleccionar un elemento del select y al presionar enter se vuelve a abrir el select con la lista de elementos, es como si al dar enter después de seleccionar un elemento este aún estuviera seleccionado para abrir el select.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Actualización: El problema se solucionó, básicamente solo se tenía que agregar la función off en la función donde se acciona el botón al presionar enter y agregar dentro de esta, la instrucción:

$('#miselect').select2('close');